# Ubuntu created a new partition from space that doesn't exist

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I just finished installing Ubuntu 19.04 next to Windows 10. In the installer I had the option to choose how much space I wanted for Ubuntu. The problem is; it didn't take anything from my existing partition on windows. This means the total space my partitions have is more than the actual space I have on my drive. I am afraid data is going to get corrupted. Do I have any options to fix this without losing data? Thanks in advance!

[image: sudo parted -l]

[image: sudo fdisk -lu]

[image: windows partitioning tool]

Comment: "The problem is; it didn't take anything from my existing partition on windows."  it never will unless you tell it to remove all windows related partition. 
" This means the total space my partitions have is more than the actual space I have on my drive" Prove it by adding the lay-out of the disks. The installer can only use unallocated space if adding Ubuntu to a dual boot so ...you probably had some.

Comment: Post these: `sudo parted -l` & `sudo fdisk -lu`.

Comment: I have edited the question with screenshots of the output of those commands @oldfred

Comment: Looks fine, you have Windows on SSD and Ubuntu on HDD, I don't see problems here.

Comment: conclusion: "This means the total space my partitions have is more than the actual space I have on my drive." is not true

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is true. The drive that contains my installation of Ubuntu has a capacity of 500GB, or ≈ 465GiB. I have added a screenshot from the partitioning tool on Windows where you can see the 'Data (D:)'-partition occupies all the space 'Schijf 0' should have (Windows uses the GB symbol but means GiB).

Comment: so it is 559Gb and you have 456+92=557 and that is less than 559.

Comment: I have looked at partition sizes and mixed MB, GB or TB sometimes. Only a 1000 difference.

Comment: @Rinzwind it's not actually 559GB.. Windows thinks it is, but I can assure you it is not. Before I installed Ubuntu, it would say 465GB. Some files already got corrupted somehow, so I am just going to completely format the drive after backing up everything that is still on there.